# Create a set of "coupon codes" based on an algorithm; no need to store the codes

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I have a situation where we print out runs of "discount cards" where a unique code is printed on the card that the user can redeem on an online store for the discount.

We create so many of these cards, with so few of them actually being used, that I'd like to use some form of way to identify a valid code using an method rather than storing each individual code in a database.  We create say 5,000 of these codes at a time. Probably about 5 times a year.

Ideally I'd like to be able to something like:

```
$coupons->generate(5000, 'unique_salt', 'prefix_');
```

Which would generate 5,000 "random" codes like:

```
prefix-23-3424-4324-3344 or
prefix-4H-34RE-22K3-PE3W
```

The `unique salt` and `prefix_` would be saved to the database. These codes would then be able to be verified by using the `prefix_` to lookup the `salt` and identify the code as valid or not.

I have a form of this working by using a number as the salt, to find numbers divisible by the salt, and then reorder the digits so that it appears random.  With long enough codes, it will take some work to figure out the pattern.  But I'd like to think there's a better way... as there's only so many numbers that yield large amounts of codes that are divisible by the `salt`.

(For example, a salt of 2 would yield 5,000 codes between 1 and 10,000 (and would be easy to see a pattern)... but a salt of 14000 would yield zero codes between 1 and 10,000)

The other advantage to this is I can generate coupons as needed (such as when we give individuals a discount on a one by one basis), and be able to track what coupons are used when, etc based on the `prefix_`... and potentially see how/when cards are passed out, what yields the best return.

Am I just spinning my wheels when I should just be storing each code in the database? (Or just having fun?) :)

Comment: I would vote for just storing the codes in the database. 5000 x 5 times / year is still only 25000 codes / year. At maybe 20-30 bytes per code, you're not even storing a full megabyte worth of data. It also avoids the issue of someone cracking the code.

Comment: You could just use some random numbers and letters, and select characters at certain indexes to generate some form of check digit that is appended to the end of the code. Then, when a code is entered, you just select the characters, run the algorithm and see if you end up with the last character.

Comment: @duncan-howe Yeah, I actually do that right now with my current method. I add select certain digits to get a total that I add to the generated code as a checksum.

Comment: I have worked on such systems to provide incentives for product registration, and we always, always went with the one-time-pad (storing them in a database) approach. I believe this is a better approach given the constraints most people are under for such a system.

Comment: @brian Yeah, I think this is ultimately what I'll do. The cost of storing codes in the database basically $0.00.  Even once we get to hundreds of thousands. It will save me time figuring out a scheme for this and make them more portable in the future.

Comment: I'd also vote for "just store them in the DB". You might be interested in my [Algorithm::CouponCode](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Algorithm-CouponCode/) tool which uses checkdigits to help your customers catch typos when entering a code. The 'index.html' link is a demo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what are you looking for is called Partial Key Verification like the serial numbers on software CDs :)

Have a look at:

http://47hats.com/2007/07/implementing-a-partial-serial-number-verification-system/

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/cdkeys.aspx

http://www.brandonstaggs.com/2007/07/26/implementing-a-partial-serial-number-verification-system-in-delphi/

Cheers

Comment: Thanks!  I thought there would be a name for it... just had no clue what it was.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using an HMAC and an appropriate encoding scheme. First, generate a secret key for the HMAC, and make sure you keep it confidential. To generate each token, do the following:

1. Generate a serial number, either at random or sequentially - all that's important is that it's unique.
2. Compute the HMAC (I suggest HMAC-SHA1) of the serial number with the secret key. This will give you a hash value (160 bits in the case of HMAC-SHA1).
3. Concatenate the serial number with part of the hash value. This is your coupon code. The number of bits of the hash value you use determines how hard it is to create a valid code by brute-force - using n bits means your attackers will have to try (on average) 2^(n-1) codes to find a valid one. Which bits you use from the hash does not matter.

To verify the code:

1. Check that the serial number is not already in your database as redeemed previously.
2. Compute the HMAC for the serial number as described above.
3. Compare the relevant bits of the HMAC to those in the rest of the code.
4. Add the serial number to your database to register it as used.

Answer (score 1):

A standard technique is to use a one-way hash on the salt and the number to create a big random looking number.  Then use this hash to generate your cryptic code.  There are a lot of standard one-way hashes that you can use.  MD5 is a common one.

To make your life easier, I would embed the number into the code in some easy way.  For instance prefix-2_-3_**-4_**-3___ would be code 2343, and then you'd fill in the blanks using data from MD5 of "prefix salt number".  That could be as simple as saying that you have an alphabet of numbers and characters you're willing to use with `n` things in it.  Take the MD5 mod `n` to pick your first character.  Divide the MD5 by `n`.  Then repeat until you have your characters.  To validate it take the prefix, look up the salt, extract the number, calculate the MD5, and follow the same procedure to generate the other characters that are supposed to be in the code.